# Why does javascript create padding in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript

I have written some javascript code that creates a preview in a table. In google chrome, however, the table gets extra padding on the bottom.

Google Chrome:

[image: Table in Google Chrome]

Internet Explore

[image: Table in Internet Explore]

I have tried the html tags   .

Prints preview text:

```
var textcontent = document.getElementById('kilo');

  textcontent.onkeyup = textcontent.onkeypress = function(){
      document.getElementById('showtext').innerHTML = this.value;
  }
```

Prints image:

```
function showMyImage(fileInput) {
    var files = fileInput.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var imageType = /image.*/;
        if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
            continue;
        }
        var img = document.getElementById("thumbnil");
        img.file = file;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
            return function(e) {
                aImg.src = e.target.result;
            };
        })(img);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

I expect a result without padding on the bottom.

Comment: Its more than likely due to how the browsers render those elements and not any particular js code. Try applying a css style to the element to specify no padding and see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

padding is CSS related, or using default value. If you need to have clear(0) paddings/margins you've to set it/them using CSS. JavaScript is not about padding but can write HTML or CSS and create element who obviously will have theirs default values. Browsers have sometimes differents settings like default or padding/margin size slightly differents, so set the needed value(s) will fix most of the problems like differences in each browser, some will require more browser specifics settings in order to set unify and erase those differences who 're oten difference of 1 or 2 px.

See also polyfil for more specifics comportements differences in browsers and lack of some modernest stuffs who exist in others and/or laters updates.

note: it's well known that IE is the worst for developpers, better use Edge who's better (stick more to W3C reccomandations) and forget about IE and version of browser who're not uptodate. Not updateing application browser is a wrong this for the user so do web sites for good and updated browsers is more likely to have a good website(i mean anyone will see the same). Testing is still needed for me but i do Firefox then Chrome and later Edge because the 2 first one more at the avant-garde of tech. and following what W3C reccomand. Teting on one or 2 not up to date could be a plus but i don't think so it's really needed, better is to display(and test) site on mobile device with mobile version browsers who 're far more in use to see and browse websites.(+ a website has to be 'mobile first' in order to get a good indexation at serach engine like Google).